# How do I parse this PHP stdClass Object?

Tags: php, parsing, object

The raw output of my object is when I do a `print_r` is:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 3 ) )
```

How do I get to the `3`?

This object is the result of a sql query inside wordpress with the `$wpdb` class.

I am a noob at PHP objects. Also would like to know

- where do I learn to do object parsing stuff like this?
- What kind of object is this? Why is it wrapped in an Array?

UPDATE: here's the source code:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts");
print_r($post_count);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to alias it in the query: `SELECT count(*) AS total FROM ....`

Comment: yep that's what I did below. Answered my own question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an object. It's an array containing an object. In that specific example, assuming that the variable is named `$variable`, you'd do this:

```
echo $variable[0]->{'COUNT(*)'};
```

Comment: P.S. I wouldn't want to work with data like that, but does anyone else think it looks sort of pretty? :)

Comment: Is this the kind of structure that is usually returned by a sql query?

Comment: I don't use Wordpress, so I don't know how it pulls out result sets.

Comment: I didn't know you could use curly braces like that in PHP (other than in code blocks). What is this structure called?

Comment: I don't know if it has a name, but using curly brackets and quoting it allows you to use characters that would otherwise not be allowed.

Comment: Is that like string interpolation in ruby? `"This is my #{name}"`

Comment: You can use it like that Amit. `echo "This is my {$name}";`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
global $wpdb;
$post_count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as postcount FROM $wpdb->posts");
print_r($post_count[0]->postcount);
```

I needed to use an alias.